# Scroll Down Without Passing Any id to page Or refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am just reading php documentation about headers. while reading I note 
that when I click on an argument it redirects me to some particular div.

So my question is How to pass user to some particular section that is in bottom means scroll-down user.

But without passing id like

```
somepage.php/article.php#mysection
```

I see that in **[this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** php documentation.when i click on `bool $replace` Or `string $header` It will redirect me to **header Div** but does not use any anchor tag.  I want to reproduce this functionality.

*I also Checked in Chrome Network Tab.* There Also Not any request is passed. So how this actuly Works.?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, what does PHP sending headers have to do with window scrolling?

Comment: i am just reading php documentation about php headers. while reading i note this thing

Comment: Oh, you want the functionality that php.net has,  they are using Javascript, [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) most likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you have to do is just found the offset of specific div & scroll down to that div.

```
    $('#banner-message').click(function(event)
    {
    var goto = $(this).attr("data-goto");
      var offsetTop = $('.'+goto).offset().top;
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 2000);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/97576/

this will animate to bottom or specific div, also it will not add any #tag in url or ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Then you can add a click handler on `button` or `a` elements that will scroll to the specific section on the page (which you may link through `data` attribute):

See: https://jsfiddle.net/5j7eqrq3/14/

e.g.

```
$(".localLink").on("click", function(){
     $(this).scrollTo($("#"+$this.data("localLink")));
})
```